# Issue with 'this' class jquery

Tags: jquery, class, this

I'm trying to insert a `this` into my function so I can have several scales.

```
$('.bt').click(function(e){
    var num = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.rat').hide(); 
    $('.' + num).show(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyPS7/)

Comment: here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kyPS7/

Comment: Which is the function you want to call using `this`?

Comment: but its working on my end

Comment: in what browser you are checking?

Comment: the thing is that if I clicked the first scale the other one gets the same, I want to be independent from each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit only one scale you can use `parent()` and `children()` functions instead of selecting elements 'globally'. Here is what you need([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyPS7/3/)):

```
$('.bt').click(function(e){
    var num = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).parent().children('.rat').hide(); 
    $(this).parent().children('.' + num).show(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the question .. i was not able to understand at all

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are selecting all elements with the class `.rat`. You want to select only the siblings of the current element. Have a look at [jQuery's siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and try something like this:

```
$('.bt').click(function(e){
    var num = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).siblings('.rat').hide(); 
    $(this).siblings('.' + num).show(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```